# How to use event .change between two input in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had two problem.

First: i had input the first, i enter  value is number into input first then change input second  . But i want it change each row when i enter value

Second : After i press enter then append a row. but why at a row which append is no change. Who can help me?thanks

code html:

```
<form id="myform" name="data" method="post">
    <div>
        <input name="salary_one[]" class="a" value="" stt=""/>
        <input name="salary_two[]" class="" value=""/>

    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="salary_one[]" class="a" value="" stt=""/>
        <input name="salary_two[]" class="" value=""/>


    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="salary_one[]" class="a" value="" stt=""/>
        <input name="salary_two[]" class="" value=""/>


    </div>
    <div id="abc">
        <input name="salary_one[]" class="a nhay" value="" stt=""/>
        <input name="salary_two[]" class="" value=""/>

    </div>

    <br>

</form>
```

code javascript:

```
    $('input[name="salary_one[]"]').change(function(){
    //$('input[name="salary_one[]"]').attr('stt',0);
    var tien=parseFloat($(this).val())*180;
    //$(this).attr('stt',1)
    //$('input[stt="1"] + input[name="salary_two[]"]').val(tien);

    $('input[name="salary_two[]"]').val(tien);
});
```

code append :

```
    $(document).on('keyup', '.nhay', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('.a').removeClass('nhay');
        $('#abc').append('<div><input name="salary_one[]" class="a nhay" value="" stt=""/><input name="salary_two[]" class="" value=""></div>');

    }

});
```

Comment: You need to better clarify your steps and desired outcome. Very difficult to read.

Comment: I mean. when i enter value input first. then value input second will change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use relationship between elements. The `next()` method can be used to get immediately following sibling then set the text.

```js
$('#myform').on('input', 'input[name="salary_one[]"]', function() {
   var tien = parseFloat($(this).val()) * 180;
   $(this).next('input[name="salary_two[]"]').val(tien); //Find sibling textbox and set value
 });


 $(document).on('keyup', '.nhay', function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
     $(this).removeClass('nhay');
     $('#myform').append('<div><input name="salary_one[]" class="a nhay" value="" stt=""/><input name="salary_two[]" class="" value=""></div>');
     e.preventDefault(); //To cancel the default action to submit the form
   }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" name="data" method="post">
  <div>
    <input name="salary_one[]" class="a nhay" value="" stt="" />
    <input name="salary_two[]" class="" value="" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: if $('#myform') different , why ?

Comment: @Louis, for example I have used it

Comment: okay thanks. It's worked.

Comment: @Louis, Use `input` event instead of `change` updated answer